# What if Ginny died in the Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter

What if Ginny died in the Chamber of Secrets and Tom was able to come back... Would that mean he would return in his 16 year old self that was preserved within the diary?

Comment: Interesting question, but has already been asked. See [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7303/21267)